# External HDD(s) Don't Appear in Files

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

A few days ago I attempted a normal backup on a 4tb external drive that I have been using for a year,(Ubuntu 20.04), but it never gets mounted or displayed in file view.However I can see it with lsusb. Tried another HDD and the same happened. I plugged in a thumb drive and no issues. Since I was running an old Ubuntu version I updated to 22.04.1 thinking perhaps an updated kernal issue caused my problems in the first place. Exact same issue; there with lsusb, nowhere to be found in files. I am not the most Linux savvy user but I am certainly confused. Worked one day and not the next, and yes there have been multiple weekly software updates I've installed for 20.04.
Any thoughts, ideas, suggestions would really be appreciated, Thanks, Tom.

Comment: Run the `mount` command, sometimes the mounted drive gets hidden in the file manager but ls still mounted also run `ls /dev/sd*` and post the results.

Comment: Open the app "Disks" and select the drive. Take a screenshot and [add it to your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438956/edit). Look for the square icon ◼️ below the picture of the partition and clock on it to turn it into a triangle ▶️.

Comment: result: ls /dev/sd* - /dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5

Comment: External device not listed in Disks. Just, internal drive and CD/DVD

Comment: Please do not use comments to add info to the question. Edit the question and add the info there so everyone can find it.